# Pop up box when loading site

Tags: php, json, google-maps

When I load this code below I have a box that pops up with LAT.LNG Any way to remove this please?

```
    $.getJSON('/aircraft.json', function(data) { 
      $.each( data.aircraft, function(i, value) {


        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon);
        alert(myLatlng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        icon: '/airplane.jpg',
        map: map,
        title: "text "+value.lon
        });



    });
```

Comment: Remove the `alert` call from your code?

Comment: Yes that worked thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your site.

In your code there is a function to retrieve and handle the coodrinates from a JSON input `/aircrat.json`. This function contains a line `alert(myLatlng)`. That line is making your popup.
`alert` is a function to make a default 'alert' to the user with the contained info.

```
  $.getJSON('/aircraft.json', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.aircraft, function(i, value) {


            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon);
            // alert(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            icon: '/airplane.jpg',
            map: map,
            title: "text "+value.lon
            });



        });
```

I have commented out the offending line in the code above.

Comment: Thanks you are a live saver! :)

Comment: Yup will do but have to wait 2 minutes to answer for some reason. Any ideas on how to make a pop up box for each aircraft to display all the data in the JSON file when clicking on marker please?

Comment: If you want one popup, I'd make a foreach loop that builds the message, then one alert after that loop to display the complete message. If you want  one alert per aircraft, just put the `alert(message)` inside the loop so that it is called for each aircraft.